# Ubuntu 17.04 Freezes when I turn off the computer (gigabyte p34)

Tags: shutdown, freeze, 17.04, i3-wm

I downloaded Ubuntu 17.04 yesterday in order to try i3 window manager in Ubuntu. Whatever, when I turn computer off it freezes on this screen. I've been using power off button since yesterday.

[image]

Comment: Try hitting the ESC key when it freezes and see if it brings you to a textual screen where you can observe the shutdown progress. Note the last thing on the screen, because it'll give you a possible clue as to why it's freezing.

Comment: I'm getting the same with Ubuntu Gnome 17.04.  Esc key does nothing.  Can't find anything in the logs.  Just freezes as soon as I click on "Power Off".  Should have stuck with 16.04 I think...